# Add logo to title page when backend is docbook

Tags: asciidoc, asciidoctor

I am trying to customise the title page where the backend output is docbook. title, subtitle etc are all output correctly. But I cannot seem to get the title logo to output.

I have tried:

```
:title-logo-image: image:images/titleimage.png[]
```

The only way I can get this to kind-of work is to directly embed the image in the title text. But that is not ideal.

Is this possible when using docbook?

Answer (score 0):

Since you convert AsciiDoc to DocBook I am assuming you are writing a book. The parameter `title-logo-image` you are using is not for **asciidoctor** (conversion to HTML and DocBook) but for **asciidoctor-pdf** (conversion to PDF), see https://docs.asciidoctor.org/pdf-converter/latest/title-page/#logo. If you are okay with PDF instead of DocBook you should try asciidoctor-pdf, it also allows you to customize your page it is pretty nice.

I am not sure what you expect though, is it a big picture on the first page? are you talking about the cover? If so you might want to create your own [DocBook cover element](https://tdg.docbook.org/tdg/5.2/cover.html) and inject it in your DocBook file. This is possible in AsciiDoc by using a [DocInfo file](https://docs.asciidoctor.org/asciidoc/latest/docinfo/). You create a *docinfo.dbk* file where you write the `<cover>` element and the file content will then be injected in the `<info>` Element in the resulting DocBook file.